# How to connect to a local docker MongoDB instance using mongo+srv?

Tags: python, linux, mongodb, docker, dns

I am working with 2 docker containers: 1 contains the back-end of my application and 1 contains the mongodb instance that I am using, both running on a linux machine. I was able to connect to the mongodb instance using the URI `mongodb://localhost:27017/`, but I was tasked to use the `mongo+srv` protocol instead. I tried `mongodb+srv://username:password@localhost/`, but that doesn't work since localhost is not allowed, nor are IP addresses. I tried [this](https://github.com/gliderlabs/resolvable) and also tried to get the 2 containers to be in the same network and use the hostname of the mongodb container in the `mongo+srv` URI, but I still don't know how to solve the problem.
Any ideas?